# Example of spring system modelled by $\ddot{x} + F(x,\dot{x}) \dot{x} + x = 0$, with given conditions on $F$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring, oscillators

Consider the oscillator equation

$$\ddot{x} + F(x,\dot{x}) \dot{x} + x = 0$$

where $F(x,\dot{x}) < 0$ if $r \leq a$ and $F(x,\dot{x}) > 0$ if $r \geq b$, where $r^2 = x^2 + \dot{x}^2$. What would be an example of a spring system (or other physical system) that might be modeled by such an equation? Thus far I have only seen spring equations of the form $ \ddot{x} + \mu \dot{x} + x = 0$, where $\mu x$ is a friction term.

Comment: Check out the [Van der Pol oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Pol_oscillator)